# How do I get dark mode on VirtualBox, with Arch Linux as the host OS?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, dark-mode

The white background in the VirtualBox manager hurts my eyes and I'd like to make it dark themed.

I'm using Arch Linux with i3, I've tried enabling dark theme in both qt5ct and lxappearance, restarting the VirtualBox manager still gave me a white background.

I've seen that some appear to have the option to indeed select a dark theme, as shown here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vjsvFnn1T4

However, I simply don't have this option. I'm using VirtualBox 7.0.12-1. The system is fully updated and there is no more recent version available as a default system package, nor as an AUR from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Dark mode was announced in version 7.0.
The current latest version is
[7.0.12](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
If it doesn't work in the installed package, try instead
to get the version from
[Download VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

You enter dark mode in *Preferences > Interface* and set the
"Color Theme" to "Dark" :

[image]

You need to close and reopen VirtualBox, which gives this result:

[image]

To see a demonstration of setting this mode, see the video
[How to Switch Between Dark and Light Mode in Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vjsvFnn1T4)